# Android CustomAdapter for a listView in a Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-dialog, android-adapter

Hi i want to make a ListView in a Dialog, with a custom ArrayList adapter, so that when i click on the item to retrieve the Object.

What i have done is the follow: 
Create a Layout with a ListView element for the Dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/dialogListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Created a Custom Layout for items in the listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

 <TextView android:id="@+id/singleItemDialogList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#336699" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have my Custom adapter

```
public class AddressBookAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<AddressBook> objects;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public AddressBookAdapter(Context context, List<AddressBook> objects) {
    this.objects = objects;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.simpleItemDialog = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.singleItemDialogList);
        convertView.setTag(holder);         
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.simpleItemDialog.setText(objects.get(position).getAddress());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public AddressBook getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView simpleItemDialog;
}
}
```

And finally where i create the dialog and set the adapter

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_list_layout, null);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogListView);
    AddressBookAdapter aba = new AddressBookAdapter(Logged.this, cachedData.getAddressBookList());
    Log.w("ABA",""+aba.getCount());
    lv.setAdapter(aba);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Log.w("CLICK","ITEM");

        }
    });
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.show();
```

Ok now when i open the Dialog i get the error: NullPointerException and points to AddressBookAdapter.getView(line 38) -> Line 38 is: `holder.simpleItemDialog.setText(objects.get(position).getAddress());`

Thank you

Comment: Does `objects.get(position)` actually return an object if you put it before line 38? That or `getAddress()` returning null is most likely the culprit.

Comment: Yes, i have tried it by displaying the number of objects i have, so the objects are populated.

Comment: Try `Log.d("AddressBookAdapter", "getAddress() " + objects.get(position).getAddress());` and then check logcat to make sure that is returning a `String` and not `null`. I don't see a problem with any other part of the code.

Comment: What is about this cachedData.getAddressBookList()?? Also post AddressBook class

Answer (score 0):

Debug and check whether your list is empty or contains any values.Your list may be null.